# jQuery Deferred chaining then() before resolving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to chain some async functions in a sync way (because each request computes a result server-side and this result changes depending on the order of the requests):

```
let updateQueue = new $.Deferred();

let dict = {
    "A": "A1",
    "B": "B1",
    "C": "C1",
    "D": "D1",
    "E": "E1",
}

let show = function(x) { 
    console.log(x); 
    /* Here comes the async part (AJAX) 
        $.ajax();
    */ 
}  

for(let prop in dict) {
    updateQueue.then(function() { show(dict[prop]); });
}

updateQueue.resolve();
```

The ouput is as I would expect it to be: see https://jsfiddle.net/oheaejcu/7/

But I don't know how the Deferred object `updateQueue` behaves when I add a `.then()` in the for loop.

- Is the output correct because each function has been called in the same order they have been queued?
- Is the output correct because function `show` is short but has been called multiple time, at the same time when `resolve()` was called?

Basically, when calling `updateQueue.then(func1)`, do I attach func1 to `updateQueue` or to the last promise resolved by `updateQueue`?

Comment: Where in your code is the "*each request's result depends on the previous one*" part? Notice also that the property order of `for in` loops is not guaranteed.

Comment: It's a server-side constraint, so I didn't showed here. I edited to make it more clear

Comment: Also thanks for noticing `for in` loops property order not guaranteed, I changed my code to use arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When calling `updateQueue.then(func1)`, do I attach `func1` to `updateQueue`

Yes. The `show` functions might be called in the same order as they were attached, but they are all called when you call `resolve()` and do not wait for each other's asynchronous parts.

> or to the last promise resolved by `updateQueue`?

No. There is only one promise in your code. To get the last promise in the chain, you need to remember then return value of the `.then(…)` call in a variable:

```
let updateQueue = Promise.resolve(); // jQuery.Deferred().resolve().promise, if you insist
for (let prop in dict) {
    updateQueue = updateQueue.then(function() { return show(dict[prop]); });
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^
}
updateQueue.then(function() { console.log("all done"); });
```

Comment: Ok, I dont get it. then() returns a promise, but I'm not using it. I'm always using the updateQueue promise. So does it means that all doneCallbacks (show function calls) are done in the same time ? Then why do I always get the good order ?

Comment: Yes, they are all called at the same time. You should notice that all your `$.ajax()` requests will run concurrently. It's just that their call are in the expected *order* (the same order as you called `then`).